# Constructor as higher-order function

Tags: java, stream, higher-order-functions

I'm facing the problem that I want to map from a Stream 4 elements to the contructor of the record Data:

```java
record Data(String firstname, String middlename, String lastname, String zip) {}

Function4<String, String, String, String, Data> constructor = Data::new;
List<Data> data = Stream.of("chris", "p", "bacon", "black")
                .map(constructor)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I found a matching higher-order function (`Function4` from vavr) to describe this constructor with 4 parameter at least. But I cant figure out how to use it in this case.

Side note: what I try to avoid is building a `Collection` of 4 elements and have to pass them "manually".:

```java
    List<Data> datas = rowData.stream()
                .map(row -> new Data(row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3))).toList();
```

I think this can't be done in Java because at some point in the stream I have to construct a type with parameter arity 4.

Comment: This is not how [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) works. `Stream::map` executes the mapper on *each* stream-element, one-by-one.

Comment: Read the documentation! Java developers have written that for a reason

Comment: @Turing85 but I don't want one by one. I want to apply 4 elements. That's the problem

Comment: @one1on I know. That is why I said that this isn't how `Stream::map` works. `Stream`s work on individual elements. Some terminal operations (like `Collectors.toMap(...)`) use some state information. But in general, streams should operate stateless. And "grouping x elements together" is not stateless.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is close to Applicative Functor which is already implemented in any monadic library, vavr also implemented it with a limitation: you can have a maximum of 8 arities. To solve your problem you have to follow this step:

- Lift each your param to Monadic world.
- Use Applicative Functor to do the rest

```
        // Validation is a monad, you lift your param here
        Validation<String,String> firstname = Validation.valid("chris");
        Validation<String,String> middlename = Validation.valid("p");
        Validation<String,String> lastname = Validation.valid("lastname");
        Validation<String,String> zip = Validation.valid("zip");

        // Here is the limitation of vavr, only Validation implement applicative functor so you can only Validation class
        // to combine four field to Data object. Beside you have to handle the error -> all the error is collected in 
        // the left side Seq<String>
        Validation<Seq<String>, Data> result = Validation.combine(firstname, middlename, lastname, zip).ap(Data::new);
```